# How to update your packages when the new R version comes out?

Tags: r

So, anytime a new 3.X R version rolls out my work is stalled because it simply creates a 3.X folder for packages and disregards all the previously installed ones which are in the folder with a previous R version name. I use this workaround:
    `.libPaths(.libPaths(), "path_to_dir_w_old_packages")`, but I have to do it everytime I launch my RStudio. I tried to manually reinstall my packages but as always there are some scientific packages that are old and maintained poorly, so there are no suitable versions for 3.X version (but libs loaded from old dir work just fine). Does anyone by chance know any solution for this annoying incommodity?

Comment: In RStudio, you can switch the version of R you are using.  So if you need to run code that uses old scientific packages, you can temporarily go back to R 3.2.

Comment: Some great suggestions in this thread: https://community.rstudio.com/t/reinstalling-packages-on-new-version-of-r/7670